# Why does MSVC fail to compile this template function?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I ran into a problem porting some code to MSVC, which puzzles me. As far as I know, the code should be legal, and Clang compiles it just fine.

I've narrowed it down to the following:

```
enum E {
    x
};

template <typename T>
struct traits {
    static const E val = x;
};

template <E e>
struct S {
    S(){};
};

template <typename T>
S<traits<T>::val> foo(T t);

int main() {
    char c = 0;
    foo(c);
}
```

Note that after compilation, the code is expected to yield a linker error (I stripped away the definition of the function `foo` to keep the sample minimal), but it *should* compile cleanly as far as I know.

However, MSVC gives me this error:

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'S::val> foo(T)'

So my question:

- is MSVC by any chance correct in rejecting the code? (and if so, why?)
- if not, can anyone narrow down what it is doing wrong? As in, is it a language feature they don't implement at all (such as two-phase name lookup for templates), or "just" a plain bug in their implementation of a feature they claim to support?

I've reproduced the problem on VC++ 2010 and 2012.

Comment: Is it related to this question from earlier today? [Is there any guarantee on the order of substitution in a function template after type deduction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462336/is-there-any-guarantee-on-the-order-of-substitution-in-a-function-template-after)

Comment: @BoPersson: Doesn't seem related to me. I can't think of anything else than a bug here. Btw it works as expected on GCC 4.7.2

Comment: Moreover, if you replace the `enum` by an `int` the error disappears. It seems to be a bug related to `enum`s

Comment: Of course it's a bug. [The compiler failed to do this or that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8kw2xcc.aspx), who cares? I need to know which language rule my program violates, with quotes from the Standard if this is something more or less obscure. Some compiler writers just have no clue. Nevertheless I would try to to instantiate `traits<char>` and `S<traits<char>::val>`, just to see how the compiler reacts.

Comment: @n.m.: Nobody said that "it's a bug" is enough of an answer. We're just writing comments. Plus, since I think this is a compiler bug, I believe the program does not violate any rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running a few tests myself, this seems to be a compiler bug in MSVC. While it works fine with GCC, MSVC gives cryptic and unhelpful compiler error (identical to the ones in your question) when you attempt to use `traits<T>::val` inside the template parameters for the `S< E e >` return.

The funny thing is, when you change `S< E e >` to take an integer instead, it works. Consider this example, identical to yours with some different naming:

```
enum E {
    x
};

template <typename T>
struct traits {
    static const E val = x;
};

template <E e>
struct S {
    S(){};
};

template <typename T>
S< traits<T>::val > tricky(T t) {
    return S< traits<T>::val > ();
};

int main() {
    char thiskidwhowalksaround = 0;
    S<x> s = tricky( thiskidwhowalksaround );
}
```

Now, let's just change *one single thing*:

```
template <int e> // int instead of E
struct S {
    S(){};
};
```

The program then compiles (links, and runs) flawlessly for me. If you also revert back to the original, and then pass in a value of `E` directly, like:

```
template <typename T>
S< x > tricky(T t) { 
// ^ here
    return S< x > (); // <-- here
};
```

Then the program compiles file. MSVC has the issue where it bites the dust at trying to do the following:

`traits<T>::val`

where `val` is any kind of enumeration. I'm 99% certain this is a deficiency in the Compiler itself. This seems to be perfectly well-formed C++ so I can't say that GCC is doing something wrong or extension-y by having the original code snippet work. Thus, the best I can glean is that MSVC is lacking in compiler robustness compared to its peers, yet again.

You can stop reading here, because now I'm going to take a small moment to rant about the MSVC compiler.

`begin<rant>`
It's not that the VC++ team is bad or that C++ is bad, but from what I glean the compiler team and the standard library teams at Microsoft -- as of time of writing -- are ***tiny*** compared to other departments. It irks me that such a fundamental and important language and part of the core of MS's industry has such comparatively little manpower that it cannot keep up with what - in my short lifetime - I find to be one of the slowest moving standards in the world. I certainly am not knocking the individuals that work on the VC++ team, but I'm deeply perplexed as to why there are not more of them working on bringing C++ not only up to speed but making the compiler work better and as good as its other product areas.
`end<rant>`

Comment: It was indeed a compiler bug. I reported it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781537/failed-to-specialize-function-template#tabs), and they just indicated that it will be fixed "in the next release of Visual C++".... Whenever that is